# Refreshing another subform upon changing a value in first

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my form called HPCC I have 2 subforms: Items_form and Item_details_form. Item_details_form is linked with Items_form so whenever you select a record in Items_form coresponding record in  Item_details_form is selected. I want to refresh Item_details_form  whenever I change Id field in Items_form I can see changes immediately without manualy refreshing whole form.

I've tried creating an event in Items_form:

```
 Private Sub nr_AfterUpdate() 
forms!HPCC!Item_details_form.Requery 
End Sub
```

`nr` is my auto incremnet primary key in both subforms.

Comment: If nr is an autonumber field it will never be directly updated from your items form so this event will never fire.  Move this code to the AfterUpdate event of your Id field on the items form, or to the AfterUpdate event of the items form itself.

Comment: "Item_details_form is linked with Items_form" - exactly how do you accomplish this? What do you mean by 'change Id field' - change how and why?